In C# what could possibly causing that when adding an item to a list, but sometimes the item is not added at the end?
I'm writing an Unity game project, in which I got an animation manager. It has a List of customized anim class instances. It's designed for, as the name shows, managing animations. However I found a bug that pointing to the this problem that I described in the question.
The code is as follows:
var anim = PoolMgr.Instance.poolAnimEnemyPlayCard.Get();
var obj = anim.gameObject;

obj.transform.SetParent(animQueue.transform, false);

anim.playHandler = AnimEnemyPlayCard;
anim.AnimFinishedCallbackHandler = () =>
            {
                PoolMgr.Instance.poolAnimEnemyPlayCard.Release(anim);
            };
anim.coord = coord;
anim.cardId = cardId;
anim.card = card;

int tempCount = animQueue.animList.Count;
animQueue.animList.Add(anim);
            
print($"add anim beforeAdd acount = {tempCount}, animQueue.animList.Count = {animQueue.animList.Count}, index = {animQueue.animList.IndexOf(anim)}");

In the console it showed:

add anim beforeAdd acount = 19, animQueue.animList.Count = 20, index =
1

This happens when the computing workload was heavy. The first thing I suspected was maybe it's caused by multithreading. I printed the managed thread ID every where I used the anim list, and they were all "1". (It should be because I didn't use multithreading codes at all). I also tried Lock(animList) when adding or using the animList, problem still exists.
More information:
The "anim" was a component attached to game objects. And I'm using an object pool to manage it. The bug disappears if I don't use the object pool, but simply Instantiate from prefab, or after calling Get() and getting an anim instance from the pool, then manually destroy the anim component only, and Add the same component to the same game object. I manually checked the component in the Unity editor inspector and can't find any difference when the bug appears or not (It appears only when the computing work is heavy, i.e. setting the game AI to calculate more cases. The AI used another thread though. But the adding animList and using it are all in the main thread).
I think the most relevant problem is why just after adding an item to a C# list, the index is 1? It should equal to the old animList.Count value, which is 19.

Is the same object in the list twice? IndexOf returns the first instance it finds in the list.

IndexOf returns the first position found. If it returned 1, it means that the anim at index 1 is the same as the anim you retrieved from the pool, and your question should be why the same object was repeatedly retrieved from the pool.

Usually, such kind of problems are caused by multiple releases of the same cached object.

omg, I'm so silly. That's the problem! Thank both of you!!! @shingo and Polynomial

I used the "UnityEngine.Pool.ObjectPool". By "realeases" do you refer to releasing the same game object or component into the pool or releasing the memory?

The problem of this post is solved. Thanks to @shingo and @Polynormial. The list has two reference of the anim instance, and the IndexOf returns the first one.
I think I know what may caused the situation after all. It's a reference I didn't cleaned up before releasing into the pool, and that dirty reference was at the index of 1 in the list. So after releasing it into the pool and getting it out, then adding it again at index of 29, the one at index 1 still exists.
